# Integral calculation $\int_0^ea^xdx$

Tags: calculus

I need help to calculate $\int_0^ea^xdx$

This should become $\frac{a^e}{ln(e)}-\frac{a^0}{ln(0)}$ and therefore not be possible but apparently it is. Help me get my head around this.

Comment: $\int a^x\,dx=\frac {a^x}{\ln a}+C$.

Comment: Hint: write $a^x=e^{x\ln a}$

Comment: You made a mistake while substituting the bounds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\int a^xdx = \frac{a^x}{\ln a} + C$ not  $ \frac{a^x}{\ln x}$

Answer (score 0):

The key... As Andrew hinted... is that $\frac{d}{{dx}}{a^x} = \left( {\ln a} \right){a^x}$. Therefore, ${a^x} = \frac{d}{{dx}}\left( {\frac{{{a^x}}}{{\ln a}}} \right)$ (since $ln(a)$ is a constant). Here's how to solve it step by step:

$${e^{x\ln a}} = {\left( {\underbrace {{e^{\ln a}}}_a} \right)^x} = {a^x}$$
$$\frac{d}{{dx}}{a^x} = \frac{d}{{dx}}{e^{x\ln a}} = \left( {\ln a} \right)\left( {{e^{x\ln a}}} \right) = \left( {\ln a} \right){a^x}$$
$$\frac{d}{{dx}}\left( {\frac{{{a^x}}}{{\ln a}}} \right) = \frac{1}{{\ln a}}\frac{d}{{dx}}{a^x} = \frac{1}{{\ln a}}\left( {\ln a} \right){a^x} = {a^x}$$
$$\int {{a^x}dx = } \int {\frac{d}{{dx}}\left( {\frac{{{a^x}}}{{\ln a}}} \right)dx = \frac{{{a^x}}}{{\ln a}} + C} $$
$$\int_0^e {{a^x}dx}  = \left. {\frac{{{a^x}}}{{\ln a}}} \right|_0^e = \frac{{{a^e}}}{{\ln a}} - \frac{{{a^0}}}{{\ln a}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$a^x= \exp(\ln(a^x)) = \exp(x\ln(a)).$

$\int_{0}^{e}a^xdx = \int_{0}^{e}\exp(x\ln(a))dx=$

$\dfrac{1}{\ln(a)}[\exp(e\ln(a)) -1]=$

$\dfrac{1}{\ln(a)}[a^e -1].$